# PHP function to remove key from a query string

Tags: php, regex

I have a query string, like:

n1=v1&n2=v2&n3=v3

etc

I just want a php function that will accept the query string and the name (key), and remove the name value pair from the querystring.

Every example I have found uses regexes and assumes that the value will exist and that it will not be empty, but in my case (and possibly in general, I would like to know) this would also be a valid query:

n1=v1&n2=&n3

I don’t know in advance how many keys there will be.

I am convinced that regexes are monsters that eat time.  Eventually all matter in the universe will end up in a regex.

Comment: I'm upping it for the regexes eat time comment... far too few people see that they are usually NOT the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
parse_str('n1=v1&n2=&n3', $gets);
unset($gets['n3']);
echo http_build_query($gets);
```

**NOTE:** `unset($gets['n3']);` is just a show-case example

Comment: Exactly what I would have suggested

Comment: @Alexander.Plutov I can't see anything wrong with this.  It seems to work for me.

Comment: @symcbean I did not mean to suggest the answer had to have something to do with regexes, it is just that the answers I found on the web all used regexes and preg_replace.  I much prefer the answers that don't.

Comment: @zod - don't worry, I guess he having mis-understanding on the question, no worry `-2 only...`

Comment: @zod. Yuo wrote `remove the name value pair from the querystring`. This code removes only value. `n1=v1&n2=`.

Comment: @Alexander.Plutov it removes both.  The example given removes 'n3' from the query string.  If you run the same code, but unset $gets['n2'] it will return n1=v1&n3=.  This is what I want.  (there are 3 names in the example (n1, n2, and n3).  n2 has an empty value, and n3 has no value at all.)

Comment: Sorry. Maybe it is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
function stripkey($input, $key) {
```

`$parts= explode("&", $input);

foreach($parts as $k=>$part) {

    if(strpos($part, "=") !== false) {
        $parts2= explode("=", $part);

        if($key == $parts2[0]){

            unset($parts[$k]);
        }
    } 
}
return join("&", $parts);`

}